# MySQL - assign dynamic categories to records and group them

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of records in mysql.. I have 5 five categories (actually time slots like 1-2 pm, 2-3 pm, 3-4 pm etc) which is not present in any field of a record..

I need to query MySQL like this -

Find all results `grouped by category1, category2` and so on and within a group `sort records by field1, field2` etc..

Actual Query looks like this -

`Group all records whose time slot fall in cat1, cat2` and so on and then `sort within this group by field1, field2, field3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is vague, but you seem to want a case:

```
select (case when time < <value 1> then 'group1'
             when time < <value 2> then 'group2'
              . . .
        end) as grp,
       count(*), . . .
from table t
group by grp
order by grp;
```

If you really want the ordering by the *time* value and not the *group* name, then use:

```
order by min(time);
```